# Why is SMTP mail putting the subject text into the body text of the email, and exception information is "blank"?

Tags: c#, .net, email, exception, smtp

This is a long shot. I have no idea why this is happening, and I am hoping this is something someone else has run into.

I have an email utility that sends me an email whenever a user gets an error, and I use it like so:

```
MyUtility.SendEmail(shortNTID,
                    "support@mycompany.com",
                    new string[] { "supportlist@mycompany.com" },
                    "Application error has occured for user: " + shortNTID,
                    "Message: " + ex.Message.ToString() +
                    " Source: " + ex.Source.ToString() +
                    " Target Site: " + ex.TargetSite.ToString() +
                    " Stack Trace: " + ex.StackTrace.ToString());
```

Now for some reason today I got some emails from the application that had this in the subject AND the body:

> Application error has occured for
>   user: Example User

That text should only be in the subject. In addition, the rest of the message body was blank, but obviously should have exception details.

To reiterate, there are two wierd things about this:

1. I have done a search through my application using "Find" for "Application error has occured for user:" and there are only a few places, and nowhere do I have this text in the message body.
2. The email is supposed to have all that exception information in the message body, and the emails had nothing but that sentence "Application error has occured for user: Example User"

Any ideas what is going on?

Comment: Is there any html content in your exception messages? Particularly ex.Message?

Comment: maybe  ex.Source or ex.TargetSite is null; you could create your message body with string.Format("App ...{0} Message ...{1} ...", ex.Message, ex.Source, ...) to avoid that

Comment: @Shiv: Not thhat I know of. It's just the standard message from the exception. @ralf: Whouldn't it throw an exception if they were null??

Comment: it would throw another exception if ex is null but maybe at that point the user just gets a messagebox with the error. Does this happen? If not, maybe you have suppressed unhandled exceptions so that message boxes aren't shown to the end user.

Comment: Also, how exactly do you get the shortNTID? You mentioned the Principal class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I'm just dumb. My SendMail method in my utility is overloaded and one of the overloads had a mistake where the subject was getting put in for the message. Problem solved. Thanks to all of you for humoring me and trying. . .

Answer (score 0):

Richard,

Check that there isn't a comma [unlikely to affect code, however...!!] (`,`) embedded inside the shortNTID variable and especially check that `ex` is in fact not null.

just a very long shot...

Comment: Thanks, but couldn't be. It's the NTID straight from the `Principal` class. . . and it happened for several different users that I know.